# jQuery addClass or other methods doesn't seem to works on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

(Sorry for my bad english)

I know, this question has been posted so many times, but the threads that I read didn't fix my problem.

I have a grid, with a random black cell drawn for each time I refresh the page. When the time come to "00:01", the cell need to replicate with the neighbors cells, I tried to put a background-color with jQuery, I tried to use attr('id', 'replicant'), I tried addClass... Nothing seem to work :S

Here the code for the draw :

```
function drawReplicant(replicant, cellTab)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < replicant.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray(replicant[i], cellTab))
        {
            var concat = 'row'+replicant[i].x+'col'+replicant[i].y;
            $(concat.toString()).addClass("replicant");
        }
    }
}
```

And here, the full code :

```
var lastClicked;
var cellTab = Array();
var replicant = Array();
var neightbors = Array();
var newReplicant = Array();

var randomRow = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var randomCol = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

var rows = 10;
var cols = 10;

var grid = clickableGrid(rows, cols,randomRow,randomCol,cellTab, function(el,row,col,i){
    console.log("You clicked on element:",el);
    console.log("You clicked on row:",row);
    console.log("You clicked on col:",col);
    console.log("You clicked on item #:",i);

    $(el).addClass('clicked');

    lastClicked = el;
});

document.getElementById("game").appendChild(grid);

function clickableGrid( rows, cols, randomRow, randomCol, cellTab, callback ){
    var i=0;
    var grid = document.createElement('table');
    grid.className = 'grid';
    for (var r=0;r<rows;++r){
        var tr = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        for (var c=0;c<cols;++c){
            var cell = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
            $(cell).addClass('row'+r+'col'+c);
            if(randomCol == c && randomRow == r)
            {
                storeCoordinate(r, c, replicant);
                $(cell).css('background', '#000000');
            }
            storeCoordinate(r, c, cellTab);
            cell.addEventListener('click',(function(el,r,c,i){
                return function(){
                    callback(el,r,c,i);
                }
            })(cell,r,c,i),false);
        }
    }
    return grid;
}


function storeCoordinate(xVal, yVal, array)
{
    array.push({x: xVal, y: yVal});
}

function replicate(replicant)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < replicant.length; i++) {
        var supRowX = replicant[i].x-1;
        var supRowY = replicant[i].y;
        storeCoordinate(supRowX, supRowY, newReplicant);
        var subRowX = replicant[i].x+1;
        var subRowY = replicant[i].y;
        storeCoordinate(subRowX, subRowY, newReplicant);
        var supColsX = replicant[i].x;
        var supColsY = replicant[i].y-1;
        storeCoordinate(supColsX, supColsY, newReplicant);
        var subColsX = replicant[i].x;
        var subColsY = replicant[i].y+1;
        storeCoordinate(subColsX, subColsY, newReplicant);
    }
}

function drawReplicant(replicant, cellTab)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < replicant.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray(replicant[i], cellTab))
        {
            var concat = 'row'+replicant[i].x+'col'+replicant[i].y;
            $(concat.toString()).addClass("replicant");
        }
    }
}

var w = null; // initialize variable

// function to start the timer
function startTimer()
{
   // First check whether Web Workers are supported
   if (typeof(Worker)!=="undefined"){
      // Check whether Web Worker has been created. If not, create a new Web Worker based on the Javascript file simple-timer.js
      if (w==null){
         w = new Worker("w.countdown.js");
      }
      // Update timer div with output from Web Worker
      w.onmessage = function (event) {
        var bool =  false;
         document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = event.data;
         if(event.data == "00:01")
         {
            replicate(replicant);
            replicant = newReplicant;
            drawReplicant(replicant, cellTab);
         }
      };
   } else {
      // Web workers are not supported by your browser
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers ...";
   }
}

// function to stop the timer
function stopTimer()
{
   w.terminate();
   timerStart = true;
   w = null;
}

startTimer();
```

The replication WORKS, I have my new replicants in my array. But when I loop in this array to draw them, it doesn't seem to work although I'm able to get the cell to draw with :

```
var concat = 'row'+replicant[i].x+'col'+replicant[i].y;
```

If my first black cell if at the row4col4 position, this line will return :

row3col4
row5col4
row4col3
row4col5

And then, when the timer will restart, those 5 black cells will replicate with their neighbors, etc.

I use a web worker for the timer, here the code :

```
var timerStart = true;

function myTimer(d0)
{
   // get current time
   var d=(new Date()).valueOf();
   // calculate time difference between now and initial time
   var diff = d-d0;
   // calculate number of minutes
   var minutes = Math.floor(diff/1000/60);
   // calculate number of seconds
   var seconds = Math.floor(diff/1000)-minutes*60;
   var myVar = null;
   // if number of minutes less than 10, add a leading "0"
   minutes = minutes.toString();
   if (minutes.length == 1){
      minutes = "0"+minutes;
   }
   // if number of seconds less than 10, add a leading "0"
   seconds = seconds.toString();
   if (seconds.length == 1){
      seconds = "0"+seconds;
   }

   if(seconds >= 20)
   {
      seconds = "00";
   }

   // return output to Web Worker
   postMessage(minutes+":"+seconds);
}

if (timerStart){
   // get current time
   var d0=(new Date()).valueOf();
   // repeat myTimer(d0) every 100 ms
   myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer(d0)},1000);
   // timer should not start anymore since it has been started
   timerStart = false;
}
```

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: the selector `'row'+replicant[i].x+'col'+replicant[i].y` does not seems to be valid

Comment: is there a element with tagName `row<something>`? - what is the selector suppose to select? are you looking for an element with the given id.. if so may be `$('#' +concat).addClass("replicant");`

Comment: Damn, i'm so stupid ! Arun, I forgotten to add the '.' at the beginning... Because it was a class. I'm so so so stupid -_- Thanks a lot guys !